# Airflow connection UI not visible

Tags: airflow

```
Airflow version: 1.10.2
Ubuntu: 18.04 (bionic)
Python: 3.6.5
```

**Issue:** I am not sure how but the connections are not visible when I click Admin in the menu. Has someone ever faced this thing?

[image]

When I edit the URL and go to localhost:8080/admin/connections I see the below response. This was working fine since

[image]

But when I list the connections from airflow cli, it works. **I am not sure why it is not visible on UI but rather accessible from cli? Or how should I give the UI user access to 'Connections'?**

Comment: could be **permissions issue**: the user with which you are logged into Airflow UI might not have `admin` privileges needed for managing `Connection`s

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to a change in 10.0.2.  Prior to 10.0.2, there was a hardcoded superuser flag for users.

To give an existing user superuser permissions, so that they can manage connections, variables, etc, you need to toggle the superuser flag in the `users` table in Airflow's metadata database.

They document how to make a user a superuser using code in the `UPDATING.md` file, see https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#user-model-changes

Comment: As of today, the link for the documentation is https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/RELEASE_NOTES.rst#user-model-changes

Answer (score 1):

Worked! I put RBAC=True in airflow.cfg and then did airflow initdb.

I am not sure why or how this issue occured but the above solution will make the Connection Ui visible again.